# Application crashes when I try to remove the title bar

Tags: java, android

I have the follwoing error:

> Missing classes One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or
>   layout_height attributs

and

> element activity is not allowed here

Here's my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.niklas.uebungsrechner.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: You can't have activities in layouts.  Activity tags should only be used in the manifest

Answer (score 3):

You  should move out:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

from your code,and end xml  with:

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: And that first bit should be in your Android Manifest

Comment: but it is stil crashing when i have this android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in the manifest (i did it like Vlado Pandzic said)

Comment: i cant see any error in android studio i just see app is closed on my smartphone

Answer (score 1):

You could also add this bit of code inside your Activity java file in the onCreate method. This way you can pick and choose easily which activity has a title and which does not.

`ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
 ab.hide();`

Answer (score 0):

this should be in your `manifest.xml` file not in your layout file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.niklas.uebungsrechner.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This should be in your mainfest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Check your values\styles.xml file in res folder to see the Base Application Theme. Replace that with the Theme.NoTitleBar in Manifest in the above code.

In the activity java file associated with your layout xml, use this code right after,

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
 try {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will hide your title bar.